# Single query to do select and update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

col1 should be set to 1 for condition = 1, and for all conditions != 1 the value of col1 should be 0.

```
SELECT col1, 
       col2 
  FROM table 
 WHERE condition1 = 1;
```

Can this be done in a single query? (instead of 1 update & 1 select).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
   SET col1 = CASE
                WHEN condition = 1 THEN 1
                WHEN condition IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE 0
              END
```

Comment: Do we need here ELSE 0, i think you are having  WHEN condition IS NULL THEN 0, which should take care.

Comment: @Sharpeye500: I don't know your data -- you're saying that the condition will always be either NULL or 1?  If so, feel free to omit the ELSE.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can write this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET col1 = (condition <=> 1)
```

This works because in MySQL the boolean value TRUE is equivalent to 1 and FALSE is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to select and also update, or are you just trying to update?

If you're just trying to update, then the SELECT query is unnecessary. Simply use:

```
UPDATE table SET col1=1 WHERE condition=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to highlight this can be done in this way too.

```
update table 
set col1=if(col1 = 1,1,0);
```